# Count if using multiple criteria in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, spreadsheet, countif

I am trying to to count the number of cells having values either 1 or mp,1 or 1,mp through `B3` to `AC3`.

Here's what I have tried so far:

```
=SUM(IF(OR(B3:AC3=1, ISNUMBER(SEARCH("1,mp", B3:AC3)),
ISNUMBER(SEARCH("mp,1", B3:AC3))),1,0))

=SUM(IF(OR(B3:AC3=1, ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH("1,mp", B3:AC3),0))), 1,
ISNUMBER(IFERROR(SEARCH("mp,1", B3:AC3),0))))

=SUM(IF(OR(B3:AC3=1, B3:AC3="1,mp", B3:AC3="mp,1"), 1, 0))`

=SUM(IF(OR(B3:AC3=1, SEARCH("1,mp",B3:AC3), SEARCH("mp,1",B3:AC3)), 1, 0))
```

Unfortunately, all of them are are giving me same error: An array value could not be found

Answer (score 0):

You can try summing COUNTIF:

```
=COUNTIF(B3:AC3,1)+COUNTIF(B3:AC3,"1,mp")=COUNTIF(B3:AC3,"mp,1")
```

Or filtering and counting values:

```
=COUNTA (IFNA(FILTER(B3:AC3, REGEXMATCH(TO_TEXT(B3:AC3),"^[1|1,mp|mp,1]$"))))
```